# Scrape a jobs board and keep persistent record

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to improve my pretty basic coding skills, and I've written this program to scrape a jobs board (I'd ultimately add several) and put the data in a db file with SQLITE3. The code works, but I can't help feeling that there are some simple things I might have done more gracefully.

One error **I know about** is that I don't have a primary key for my DB. I'm going to add this! In the meantime, I've just been querying the DB with something like 
`SELECT DISTINCT Title, Company FROM jobs WHERE Date BETWEEN datetime('now', '-3 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');` which works nicely.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

```
import csv
import datetime
import urllib.request
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil import parser

"""
Scrapes STA jobs board, adds new jobs into a database
"""


def update_db():
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('jobs.db')
        c = conn.cursor()

        # call the scraping functions
        soup = scrape_secret()
        jobs = clean_jobs(soup)
        result = organise(jobs)
        final = data_cleanser(result)
        export(final)

        # after exporting to csv (just in case) we delete the title row and convert nested lists to tuples
        del final[0]
        new_result = [tuple(l) for l in final]
        # only necessary once
        # c.execute('''CREATE TABLE jobs (Title, Company, Location, Type, Date Posted)''')

        c.executemany("INSERT INTO jobs VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", new_result)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    except Error as e:
        print(e)


# function to remove multiple occurrences of one term ('new')
def remove_value_from_list(the_list, val):
    return [value for value in the_list if value != val]


def length_enforcer(the_list, length):
    return [value for value in the_list if len(value) == length]


# hit the website and scrape the first page
def scrape_secret():
    url = "https://jobs.secrettelaviv.com/"
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    return BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")


def clean_jobs(soup):
    # jobs are in 'spans'
    all_spans = soup.find_all("span")
    jobs = []
    for span in all_spans:
        jobs.append(span.get_text().strip())
    # remove extraneous elements
    jobs.remove('')
    jobs.remove('Subscribe to our EVENTS Newsletter')
    jobs.remove('Join our facebook GROUP')
    jobs = remove_value_from_list(jobs, '')
    return remove_value_from_list(jobs, 'new')


def organise(jobs):
    # make list of lists
    result = [["Title", "Company", "Location", "Duplicate", "Type", "Date Posted"]]
    new_list = []
    for job in jobs:
        if len(new_list) == 6:
            a = list(new_list)
            result.append(a)
            new_list = [job]
        else:
            new_list.append(job)
    result.append(new_list)
    return length_enforcer(result, 6)


def data_cleanser(result):
    for i in result:
        del i[3]
        try:
            i[4] = parser.parse(i[4])
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return result


def export(result):
    csvfile = "secret_today" + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d') + ".csv"
    with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerows(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_db()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be used in `clean_jobs`, if you prefer list comprehension:

```
jobs = [span.get_text().strip() for span in all_spans]
```

`export` and `final` are reserved keywords in other languages, so they stand out a bit, to me. In either case, using more descriptive names for both could increase legibility.

The `jobs.remove` calls could be replaced with something like this (since more strings are almost guaranteed to appear in the future):

```
rem_list = ['',
            'Subscribe to our EVENTS Newsletter',
            'Join our facebook GROUP']
for removal_string in rem_list:
    jobs.remove(removal_string)
```

Adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top is a healthy habit, for specifying that the source code is in UTF-8 (which is a good default).

Otherwise, I don't think the code looks too shabby. Code for scraping the web will never look squeaky clean, since there are many specifics to handle.

Answer (score 3):

#### Code Quality and Other Improvements

- I would use a cursor and a connection as *context managers* to avoid having to explicitly close them and let Python safely close them if an error happens:

  ```
  with sqlite3.connect('jobs.db') as connection:
      with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  ```
- making the query defined as a *multi-line string* could benefit readability:

  ```
  cursor.executemany("""
      INSERT INTO 
          jobs 
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", new_result)
  ```
- watch for PEP8 code style violations - for instance, [organize imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) in a proper way

#### Performance

We can definitely do better performance-wise:

- switch from `lxml` to `html.parser` (requires `lxml` to be installed):

  ```
  BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
  ```
- since you need only `span` elements, let `BeautifulSoup` [parse only them](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document):

  ```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

  parse_only = SoupStrainer('span')
  BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml", parse_only=parse_only)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. I had some blips with the CM implementation, (the Python DBAPI precedes context managers so every RDBMS lib handles it differently, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568137/is-enter-and-exit-behaviour-for-connection-objects-specified-in-the-pyth)) but in the end I got it to work without a cursor with `with sqlite3.connect('jobs.db') as con:
        con.executemany`